# How to specify lambda function and IAM role name in cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

here is my template

```
{  
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
   "Resources":{  
      "lambdafunction":{  
         "Type":"AWS::Lambda::Function",
         "Properties":{  
            "Handler":"index.handler",
            "Role":{  
               "Fn::GetAtt":[  
                  "RootRole",
                  "Arn"
               ]
            },
            "Code":{  
               "S3Bucket":"{s3_bucket_name}",
               "S3Key":"lambda-zip"
            },
            "Runtime":"java8",
            "Timeout":"25"
         }
      },
      "RootRole":{  
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
         "Properties":{  
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument":{  
               "Version":"2012-10-17",
               "Statement":[  
                  {  
                     "Effect":"Allow",
                     "Principal":{  
                        "Service":[  
                           "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                        ]
                     },
                     "Action":[  
                        "sts:AssumeRole"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "Path":"/",
            "Policies":[  
               {  
                  "PolicyName":"root",
                  "PolicyDocument":{  
                     "Version":"2012-10-17",
                     "Statement":[  
                        {  
                           "Effect":"Allow",
                           "Action":"*",
                           "Resource":"*"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The name of the lambda function after the stack creation is 
lambda-lambdafunction-18SJKJ5Q40AKZ
The name of IAM role is 
lambda-RootRole-12S8E9CA0EOVM

The template does not seem to have a way to define the lambda function name http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html. And I am not sure why random characters are appended at the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: both AWS::IAM::Role and AWS::Lambda::Function now support custom names.

By default, CloudFormation generates a unique ID for resource names. This makes sense because it allows you to re-use the template again and again.

Some resource types, but not all, support custom names. Examples that do support custom names are AWS::DynamoDB::Table ('TableName') and AWS::S3::Bucket ('BucketName').

For more info, and a complete list of resources that support custom names, see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-name.html).

Comment: Thanks jarmod. As you said I was able to define custom names for dynamo db table / s3 buckets. If those resources allow customs names I don't see why the same functionality is not available for lambda fns and IAM roles. I am able to define custom names using aws cli though.

Comment: @premprakash I'm not sure what criteria Amazon uses to decide which resources can have custom names, or even if there's actually a compelling reason for it.

Comment: PS may be worth denoting this response as the answer to guide others with the same question in future.

Comment: Names are allowed now with the `FunctionName` property, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I discovered that "FunctionName" allows you to name the Lambda functions:

```
 "LambdaResourceName": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "FunctionName": "",
        "Description": "",
        "Handler": "app.handler",
        "Role": 
        "Code": 
    "Runtime": "node.js"
```

Comment: This doesn't work with SAM Transformations adding FunctionName: will cause the Transformation Change set to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use "RoleName" in properties of Role and "FunctionName" in properties of Lambda to give specific names to Lambda function and Role being created.